# Show that $\left\{A\subset\Omega: A~\text{ is countable or }A^C\text{ is countable}\right\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> > Let $\Omega$ a set and
> >     $$
> > C=\left\{A\subset\Omega: A~\text{ is countable or }A^C\text{ is countable}\right\}.
> > $$
> >     Show that $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that
> >     $$
> > \sigma(\left\{\left\{ x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\})=C.
> > $$

Hello!

First I have to show that $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Here are my results; I have some problems to finish the proof.

**(1)** If $\Omega$ is countable, then $\Omega\in C$. If $\Omega$ is not countable, then $\Omega^C=\emptyset$ is. So in any case $\Omega\in C$.

**(2)** Consider $A\in C$. If $A$ is countable, then $A^C$ is in $C$, because $(A^C)^C=A$ is countable then. If $A$ is not countable, it has to be by definition $A^C$ countable (otherwise $A$ could not be in $C$), so $A^C$ in $C$.

**(3)** Consider $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in C$. First case: All $A_i, i=1,2,\ldots$ are countable. Then $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_i$ is countable as countable union of countable sets. So $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_i\in C$. Second case: All $A_i, i=1,2,\ldots$ are not countable. Then all $A_i^C, i=1,2,\ldots$ are countable and for any $i\in\left\{1,2,.\ldots\right\}$ it is
$$
\left(\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_i\right)^C=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}A_i^C\subset A_i^C
$$
which means that $\bigcap_{i\geq 1}A_i^C$ is countable. So it follows that $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_i$ is in $C$, because its complement is countable.

Now what is with the third case, that some $A_i$ are countable and others not? Do not know how to handle it.

Overmore, I have problems to show $\supset$ of the identity that is to show. The other implikation $\subset$ follows, because $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (which I have not completely shown) and $\left\{\left\{ x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\}\subset C$.

---

So would you please help me to finish point **(3)** (case 3) and the implication $\supset$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't need a third case. If there is some $A_j$ that is not countable, then $A_j^C$ is countable, so by the same reasoning, $$\left(\bigcup_{i\ge 1} A_i\right)^C\subseteq A_j^C,$$ so the countable union is an element of $C$.

As a hint for the other part, show that every countable subset of $\Omega$ is an element of $\sigma\bigl(\{\{x\}:x\in\Omega\}\bigr),$ so every subset of $\Omega$ with a countable complement is again such an element, and so $C$ is a subset of $\sigma\bigl(\{\{x\}:x\in\Omega\}\bigr).$

Comment: If $A\in C$ is countable, then $A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\left\{x\right\}$ and this is a countable union of elements in $\left\{\left\{x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\}$ and so in $\sigma(\left\{\left\{x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\})$. If $A\in C$ isnot countable, then $A^C$ is, so with the same argument, $A^C\in\sigma(\left\{\left\{x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\})$ and (because this is a $\sigma$-algenra) $A\in\sigma(\left\{\left\{x\right\}: x\in\Omega\right\})$. Right?

Comment: Absolutely right!

Comment: Could you explain why is "so by the same reasoning" true?

Comment: @FrishMagmol, apply DeMorgan's Law of the complement of a union to see why.

Comment: The complement of the unions is the intersection of the complements, that's ok but why is the intersection of the complements a subset of $A_j^c$

Comment: Oh ok, I draw a picture using two set A,B and understand what you said. Pretty obvious now...Thanks

Comment: @FrishMagmol, glad to help! Well done. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For **(3)**:

Let $A=\bigcup_i A_i$, with at least one (say $A_0$) of the $A_i$'s not countable. We know that $A_0^C$ is countable by assumption so
$$ A^C=\bigcap_i A_i^C \subset A_0^C$$
is also countable, so $A\in C$.

For **$\supset$**:

It is enough to prove that every countable subset is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by singletons. But this is obvious, since
$$ A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x\}$$
and $A$ is countable so the union is countable.